# dotnetacademy final exam issue C#

Tags: c#, .net, list, generic-list

I am currently trying to learn C# through dotnetacademy. In the final exam I am on last step where the instructions are:

> 1. Please modify the entry point method to declare an instance of the Survey type. After the declaration, add two text questions to the survey of your choice.
> 2. Next, after the two question declarations, create a new local declaration that returns the result of the GetScore method.
> 3. Finally, print the message "Your score: {Score}" to the Console using WriteLine, where {Score} is the score obtained from the survey.

I have managed to complete the last two steps I think because I can print the score. I need help with step 1.

Here is my code:

`using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;



public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string [] args)
    {
        Survey survey = new Survey("Survey");
        survey.Questions.AsReadOnly();
        TextQuestion tq = new TextQuestion();

        survey.AddQuestion((Question)tq.Ask());
        int score = survey.GetScore();
        Console.Write("Your score: {0}", score);

    }
}

public abstract class Answer
{
    public int Score { get; set; }
}


public abstract class Question
{
    public string Label { get; set; }

    protected abstract Answer CreateAnswer(string input);

    protected virtual void PrintQuestion()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Label);
    }

    public Answer Ask()
    {
        PrintQuestion();

        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        return CreateAnswer(input);
    }
}

public class TextAnswer : Answer
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class TextQuestion : Question
{
    protected override Answer CreateAnswer(string input)
    {
        return new TextAnswer { Text = input, Score = input.Length };
    }
}

public class Survey
{
    public Survey(string title)
    {
        Title = title;
        Questions = new List<Question>();
    }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public List<Question> Questions { get; private set; }

    public void AddQuestion(Question question)
    {
        Questions.Add(question);
    }

    public int GetScore()
    {
        int total = 0;
        foreach (Question question in Questions)
        {
            Answer answer = question.Ask();
            total = total + answer.Score;
        }

        return total;
    }`

I can't add a Question to the survey instance because it requires a question parameter of Question type. Any suggestions?

And finally, this is the link to the exercise: [Exercise](https://dotnetcademy.net/Learn/2051/Pages/9)

Comment: Try `survey.AddQuestion(tq)`?

Comment: before survey.AddQuestion(tq) put tq.Ask();

Comment: The tutorials in that course do explain what to do in order to complete the question, and looking at where you have gotten to so far it looks like you need to do a bit more learning. Please do not use SO for help with exams as it detracts from your learning experience.

Comment: Yes I have tried that and I do not get an compilation error but isn't that just an instance of TextQuestion? I am supposed to add two text questions, but maybe I am thinking weird, but I want to pass a string although it only takes a Questions as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of you guys it now passes:

```
    public static void Main()
{
    Survey survey = new Survey("Survey");
    Question tq1 = new TextQuestion();
    Question tq2 = new TextQuestion();
    tq1.Ask();
    tq2.Ask();
    survey.AddQuestion(tq1);
    survey.AddQuestion(tq2);

    int score = survey.GetScore();
    Console.WriteLine("Your score: {0}", score);

}
```

}